# Does a digitigrade biped need a tail?

Tags: xenobiology, aliens, digitigrade-species

One of my writing buddies keeps insisting that my biped/digitigrade alien species would need a tail to act as a counterweight and shift their centers of gravity. Would a tail be required?

EDIT:// the species is pretty upright like a human.

Comment: (a) I removed the word "opinion." We're not a discussion forum. We only answer specific questions. (b) I'd rather not VTC the question, but it's missing a lot of detail to give you a meaningful answer. Can you describe your species? Can you explain what you've done to resolve the question of balance? (c) Or, frankly, it's your world. Go watch [The Arrival](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115571/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_49) then tell your friend to jump in the lake. Just because all the digitigrade critters on Earth have tails means absolutely nothing.

Comment: ...I guess that's true, lol. Thanks, @JBH.

Comment: without knowing what said creature looks like there is no way to answer this.

Answer (score 4):

## It's a matter of Posture.

[image]

Essentially, whether you need or not a tail is mostly dependent on your creature's posture. This can be seen easily with us, modern birds and theropod dinosaurs.

We have our center of balance fairly close to a point right above where our legs begin. Because of this positioning, we don't need tails, but maintaining balance while heavily hunched over is very tricky as a result. In fact, because of how our center of balance is placed, suddenly attaching a heavy tail to a human will actually compromise their balance, forcing them to take a more hunched posture in order to balance it out.

Modern Birds have a very similar situation: their center of balance being close to their legs, meaning they too don't need long or heavy tails, ideal as most of them need to remain as light as possible, and the ones who don't can also benefit from having an easier time changing direction without needing a tail to be used as a rotor or counterweight. At worse, some species have centers of balance slightly tilted forwards, balanced by their pelvis without requiring a heavy tail.

The classic Theropod dinosaurs (such as T-Rex, velociraptors and dakotaraptors), on the other hand, had their center of balance further away from their legs, closer to the front of their bodies. As a result, they needed heavy tails to act as counterbalances.

Where your center of balance lies still remains as one of the main factors, and that holds true even if you were to have backwards facing legs, or any kind of leg really. If, for example, they were quadrupedal like bears, they'd also not need a tail, as their front limbs help supporting their weight and maintaining balance, thus not requiring a heavy tail or counterbalance.

So, summing up, whether they need a heavy counterbalance tail or not is mostly reliant on how their posture is and the number and position of limbs supporting their weight:

- Bipedal with Dinosaur-like posture and/or center of gravity away from legs? A tail or a similar counterweight is needed (this would still be true even if the animal had its body and center of gravity pointing backwards, except they would instead need a counterweight pointing forwards, be it a tail or something else).
- Bipedal with an upright posture and/or with a center of gravity close to the legs? Again, not necessary, but a rotor-like tail could still see use aiding in changes of direction while running depending on their anatomy, as long as it remained light as not to shift their center of balance towards the back, turning them into a more theropod-like body plan (as we see in the roadrunner's light tail adorned with long tail feathers used to change direction quickly like we suspect raptors did). As long as their center of balanced isn't too far away from the supporting legs, simple changes in their structure might be more than enough to balance it out without needing a long and/or heavy tail.
- A quadruped? Similar to last case: the presence of 4 limbs means that whether center of mass is close to either pair or somewhere in the middle, it'll still be adequately supported.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not required. Bipedalism on it's own shifts the centre of gravity, all balancing mechanisms can develop to go with it, a tail is not required. The common ancestor of apes lost it's tail and balanced just fine in trees.

Comment: The specific issue is digitigrade legs or legs turned backwards like a birds' legs. Addressing bipedalism alone does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @JBH huh? Digitigrade means walking on toes, no animal has back to front legs, they just walk on the toes wwhich means the ankle functions differently.

Comment: That's the simple Google definition. Go look at the images. Digitigrade legs use reversed knees (bending to the back rather than to the front). While we could argue, I'm certain the OP would confirm that's the case here.

Comment: @JBH that's actually a common misconception. Digitigrade creatures have knees just like most other animals. The big difference is that the metatarsals are lengthened. In the case of birds specifically, their metatarsals have also fused into a single bone. That, coupled with the fact that their thigh bones are usually both small and internal rather than external causes the illusion that birds have backwards knees, when in truth those are just their ankles. If you want something closer to actual backwards knees, you might be better off looking at bats instead.

Comment: @ProjectApex Your point is well taken! But we'd need a clarification from the OP.

Comment: @JBH you're confusing ankles for knees. OP doesn't need to clarify what digitigrade means, it's a fully defined English word.

Comment: [https://www.google.com/search?q=digitigrade&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X](https://www.google.com/search?q=digitigrade&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) Unless the OP clarifies otherwise, those images are what most people have in mind when they hear the word.

Comment: @JBH I just use a dictionary or my encyclopedias, I'm going to assume the OP understands English at least as well if not better than myself as it's not my primary language. I read definitions, looking at pictures was back in my comic reading days.

Comment: You're making terrible assumptions. [Here's the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitigrade). Yup, you're absolutely right, the birds have ankles, yada yada yada... but what's in people's heads isn't at all what you're talking about. I continue to assert your answer is poor because bipedalism isn't the issue. What's in the OP's head when he (not you) uses the word "digitigrade," is. Gratefully this is all academic. The OP walked away from this Q yesterday.

Comment: @JBH just in your head perhaps, no one else has trouble with it. I'm just assuming the OP understands English, thats not a 'terrible assumption'. Feel free to downvote.

Comment: Deal. Oddly, everyone but you has understood what the OP meant. You're the only one on this side of the fence (note ProjectApex's lovely pictures showing exactly what everyone else concluded... reflected by the images on the wiki page... reflected by the images on Google image search...).

Comment: @JBH na, just you didn't understand, you've done the downvote, now go away and dribble elsewhere please.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Friend is Wrong**

[image]

Humans are not digitigrade. But they can become digitigrade by standing on their tippytoes.

Your homework is to try this for yourself and see if you fall down -- even without a tail.

It stands to reason that a species that is naturally digitigrade would be even better at not falling over, and be able to stay on their toes all day without the muscles tiring out.